# Sub inside a UserForm can't receive Worksheet as parameter

Tags: excel, vba

for my internship I have to do some excel UserForms and vba macros. 
I have a `Private Sub` inside my `UserForm` and i need to pass a WorkSheet as parameter to it. But i always get

> "Execution error 438"

when the `Sub` is called.

What bothers me is that `FirstBlankColumn` works but `FillAllBox` doesn't.

I tried:

-putting FillAllBox in Public and neither Private nor Public

-turning FillAllBox into a Function

-changing the way i pass the Worksheet (ie: `Set ws = Worksheets("ExportedData")` then passing`ws`)

```
'''vba
Private Function FirstBlankColumn(ws As Worksheet) As Long
   'Yadda yadda does some stuff
   '
   'returns the number of the first blank column
End Function


Private Sub FillAllBox(ws As Worksheet)
    ' we never get to the FillBox calls
    FillBox UserBox, ws
    FillBox StockTransBox, ws
    FillBox SemaineBox, ws
    FillBox LocationBox, ws
    FillBox ValeurBox, ws
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' displays correctly the number of the first blank column
    MsgBox FirstBlankColumn(Worksheets("ExportedData"))
    ' Throws "error 438" upon call
    FillAllBox (Worksheets("ExportedData"))
End Sub
'''
```

For a long time i passed the Sheet names and String to pass sheet as parameters. But having to call the sheet list in every function/sub to retrieve my sheet isn't optimised.

I'd like to be able to directly pass Sheets or Worksheets as parameter, reliably.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is your use of parentheses(()). Remove those from your call and you should be good to go.

Here is Microsoft's documentation on the use of [parentheses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-parentheses-in-code).

> Sub procedures, built-in statements, and some methods don't return a value, so the arguments aren't enclosed in parentheses
>
> Function procedures, built-in functions, and some methods do return a value, but you can ignore it. If you ignore the return value, don't include parentheses. Call the function just as you would call a Sub procedure. Omit the parentheses, list any arguments, and don't assign the function to a variable.

```
 FillAllBox Worksheets("ExportedData")
```

Comment: Ok thanks. So my call of FillAllBox was incorrect due to too many parentheses, but it was correct for FirstBlankColumn since FirstBlankColumn has a return value and FillAllBox has not ?

Comment: @Mummoc `FirstBlankColumn` returns a `Long`, and you are capturing the function's return value (and passing it to the `MsgBox` function) so you have `MsgBox FirstBlankColumn(Worksheets("ExportedData"))`. If you did `MsgBox FirstBlankColumn((Worksheets("ExportedData")))` instead, you would still be let-coercing a `Worksheet` object reference (note the extra parentheses), and it would throw the exact same error.

Comment: An easy way to remember it is if you are returning something from a function then you need to use parentheses. So anytime you use an equal sign `=` the right-hand side function will need parentheses. If you use a function as a parameter then that function will need it as well since it is returning something.

Comment: @Mummoc also pay attention to the whitespace the VBE is adding between a function/procedure's name and its argument list. If there's a space, the parentheses are NOT delimiting the argument list, they're telling VBA to evaluate the parenthesized expression as a value, and pass that value to the invoked procedure. e.g. `MsgBox ("message")` vs `MsgBox "message"` vs `foo = MsgBox("message")`.